# Given partially sorted array of type x<y => first apperance of x comes before first of y, sort in average O(n)

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

i was given an assignment to find an algorithm that takes an array A such that for every x<y we have the first appearance of x coming before the first appearance of y
and sorts it in average time of O(n)

an example array could be 1,2,1,30,1,1,2,1,40,30,1,40,2, 50, 40, 50, 30
and the output should be 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 50, 50

i should show that the suggested algorithm runs in O(n) on average.

i have no clue where to start..
the only thing i know is how to theoretically analyse the average case of a loop or nested loops
for very specific cases

any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In one iteration over the input array you can:

- Collect the unique values in their order of first appearance
- Count how many you have of each

(Both can be captured by using a hash map that maintains insertion order, like for instance a dict in Python 3.6+, a Map in JavaScript, or a LinkedHashMap in Java)

With this information you can produce the sorted output.

Here is a runnable implementation with an execution of your example input:

```js
function sort(data) {
    const map = new Map;
    for (const value of data) {
        const count = map.get(value) ?? 0; // 0 is default
        map.set(value, count + 1);
    }
    const result = [];
    for (let [value, count] of map) {
        while (count-- > 0) result.push(value);
    }
    return result;
}

const data = [1,2,1,30,1,1,2,1,40,30,1,40,2, 50, 40, 50, 30];

console.log(sort(data));
```

Comment: This is a practical example if im using the optimized hashmaps of some language

Comment: But im looking for an answer where if you use a hashmap , average case of O(n) should be shown by introducing the hashing function.. i dont think i can even you hashing here or counting, as i dont know how large the numbers be, theoretically they can be inf

Comment: If the values can be arbitrarily large, then even *reading* all the numbers is not O(), but O() where  is the average (or max) logarithm of the values in the input. So then what you ask is not possible. Please clarify.

Comment: i need an average case of O(n) not worst case

Comment: Yes, I speak of average case.

Comment: i mean i could use direct access table with keys in set (unique keys) as what u shown
but how do i explain that its theoretically feasble without knowing anything about the range of values, in average O(n) time

that was the assignment at my DS class, so i assume it must be possible some how